# Verwendung von »Kretin«

Tags: word-usage, insult

Benutzt man die Beleidigung *Kretin* im Deutschen noch? Ist sie ernst zu nehmen?

Auf mich wirkt das Wort so hochgestochen und antiquiert, dass ich es persönlich albern und nicht provokant fände. Ich frage nicht nach der Wortgeschichte, sondern nach der Benutzung von *Kretin* in der Gegenwartssprache.

Comment: In der deutschen Sprache habe ich das Wort bisher noch nie gehört; in Polen benutzt man "kretyn" aber sehr gerne und oft, wenn man jemanden beleidigen möchte. Ob es in der Hinsicht irgendwelche sprachliche Einflüsse gibt?

Comment: Das deckt sich mit meinem Eindruck. Sprechen Sie Deutsch als Muttersprache (soll heißen, sind Sie mit Deutsch aufgewachse? Auch wenn sie offenbar eine Zweitsprache haben)?

Comment: Ich bin deutscher Muttersprachler und kenne das Wort auch überhaupt nicht.

Comment: Ich (Berliner) kenn das durchaus, benutze es aber nie, da es sonst keiner zu kennen scheint. Als hochgestochen empfinde ich es aber nicht.

Comment: @usario Deutsch ist meine 2. Muttersprache

Comment: Also ich habe es schon im (pseudointelektuellen Umfeld, ähem...) gehört. Für mich: Passiver Wortschatz definitiv, im aktiven seeeeehr selten. Vielleicht drei, vier mal in knapp 40 Jahren? Und ja, "hochgestochen" und "möchtegern" sind passende Adjektive.

Comment: Ich bin ein 50-jähriger österreichischer Muttersprachler und kenne das Wort sehr wohl. Als hochgestochen (im Sinn von überheblich) empfinde ich es nicht, als veraltet hingegen schon. »Kretin« gehört nicht zu meinem aktiven Wortschatz. Ich vermute, dass die Menschen in meinem persönlichen Umfeld das Wort auch kennen, aber kaum verwenden. Ich glaube mich erinnern zu können, das Wort öfter in Hans-Moser-Filmen und ähnlichen Filmen gehört zu haben, bin mir dessen aber nicht sicher.

Comment: Bin auch deutscher Muttersprachler. Kenne das Wort zwar, habe es auch "schonmal irgendwo..." gehört, aber es ist absolut unüblich. Einige Leute werden nicht wissen, was damit gemeint ist. Ich kann mich noch erinnern, dass dieses Wort in den deutschsprachigen Lustigen Taschenbüchern (Disney) früher genutzt  wurde, von heute weiß ich es nicht.

Comment: Kretin ist eigentlich jemand der am Kretinismus erkrankt ist.http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kretinismus In dieser Form wird das Wort aber mit sicherheit NICHT mehr verwendet. Wenn überhaupt, dann als Beleidigung gegenüber Menschen die einem suspekt sind oder die man in irgendeiner Weiße für unterlegen hält.

Comment: Wie der Barth würde ich sagen es kommt in Osteuropa auf allen Sprachen, auch auf Deutsch, häufiger vor als in der heutigen Bundesrepublik. Ich halte es für international also quasi von jedem Europäer bekannt, wenn auch mit unterschiedlicher Häufigkeit benutzt. Also finde ich die Frage sollte lauten »in Deutschland« nicht »im Deutschen«.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In gedruckten Werken findet [Google-NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Kretin&year_start=1750&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CKretin%3B%2Cc0) seit ca. 1940 eine etwa konstante Verwendung des Wortes, 1910, 1850 und um 1800 war das Wort wesentlich stärker verbreitet.

Gegenwartssprache ist auch, das kann man leicht übersehen, was über 80jährige sprechen und was nur in gewissen Milieus gesprochen wird - daher sind eigene Erfahrungen notorisch unzuverlässig.

Wörter, die wie *Kretin* etwas antiquiert daherkommen aber im passiven Wortschatz weit verbreitet sind können auch durch ein Medienereignis spontane Popularität erreichen, ich erinnere da an *Neuland*.

Google News zeigt, dass es in jüngster Zeit in der Presse noch geläufig ist.

Comment: Der Google-Korpus ist aber doch rein schriftsprachlich und auch noch auf Bücher beschränkt, wenn ich mich nicht täusche. Er ist also gerade für tatsächlich benutzte Beleidigungen nicht besonders aussagekräftig. (PS: Ich kenne das bildungssprachliche Genus von _Korpus_.)

Answer (score 10):

Nach [Wortschatz Leipzig](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/cgi-portal/de/wort_www?site=208&Wort_id=45022812) ist das Wort nur 6 Häufigkeitsklassen unter *Idiot*, wird also ca. 64 mal seltener verwendet. Der geäußerten These, eine weniger gebräuchliche Beledigung sei weniger ernst zu nehmen, kann ich mich nicht anschließen. Es kann sowohl harmloser sein („versteht das Wort eh nicht, ist also weniger beleidigt“) als auch heftiger („wenn es schon mit Unkenntnis des Wortes anfängt …“).

Und ja, ich verwende das Wort.

Answer (score 4):

*Kretin* ist auch heute noch ein durchaus gebräuchlicher Terminus für *Idiot, Dummkopf, schwachköpfiger Trottel* etc.; entscheidend für die Häufigkeit der Benutzung ist – unabhängig voneinander – sowohl der geographische Standort als auch die soziale Schicht. In gesellschaftlichen Kreisen, die Wert auf Abgrenzung zur sozialen Unterschicht legen, ist der Begriff durchaus geläufig.

Ferner wird er in den westlichen Gebieten des moselfränkischen Dialekts, der mit vielen eingedeutschten französischen Begriffen durchzogen ist, von allen Bevölkerungsschichten benutzt (die Gegend um Trier, Hunsrück und Saargebiet).

Comment: Servus und willkommen beim Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache. Du kannst eine [tour] der Seite nehmen. Näheres darüber, wie sie funktioniert, erfährst du im [help]. Und für die Antwort gibts +1 für den Einstieg ;)

Answer (score 2):

Das Wort ist weder hochgestochen noch antiquiert, und die Benutzung des Wortes Kretin ist auch in der Gegenwartssprache noch relevant; natürlich ist es weder denglisch noch neudeutsch. Allerdings ist die Häufigkeit der Verwendung wohl auch regional unterschiedlich.
Vielleicht könnte man es für manche mit dem Zusatz "Alter" etwas hipper gestalten.
Frage an die Kritiker, die den Ausdruck mit etwas "seltsamen" Adjektiven belegen: nennen Sie doch mal bitte ein absolut adäquates Synonym...

Comment: Servus und willkommen auf dem Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache. Du kannst eine [tour] der Seite nehmen. Beachte, wegen deines letzten Satzes, dass wir kein Forum sind, sondern strikt einem Frage-Antwort-Muster folgen. Näheres, und alles weitere, was die Seite ausmacht, erklärt dir das [help]. Ansonsten auf gute Zusammenarbeit.

Comment: Ok, wir wissen jetzt, dass Du eine Meinung hast. Hast Du auch eine Antwort?

Comment: @CarstenS Ich sehe eine in den ersten drei Sätzen …

Comment: @Jan: Ich möchte auf »den ersten **beiden** Sätzen« verkürzen. Den dritten Satz (»Vielleicht könnte man ...«) zähle ich nicht mehr zu dem Teil, der die Frage beantwortet, sondern zu dem Teil, in dem eine ungefragte Meinung kundgetan wird. (Hinweis an G Nius: Das ist ok. Meinungen darf man äußern, wenn man auch die Frage beantwortet, was du ja getan hast.) Allerdings steht der letzte Satz (»Frage an die Kritiker ...«) tatsächlich den expliziten Regeln dieses Mediums entgegen. Dies ruft aber nicht mehr als erigierte Zeigefinger einiger Kommentatoren hervor, mit denen dann Rügen getippt werden.

Comment: Richtig ist, dass Kretin nicht Denglisch ist, sondern aus dem Französischen kommt: crétin.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Du hast recht; ich habe den Strichpunkt irrtümlich als Satztrenner gesehen, sollte also meinen vorigen Kommentar auf *zwei* korrigieren.

Answer (score 1):

In meiner Wahrnehmung (Niedersachsen) gehört *Kretin* zum Jargon von Kulturschaffenden und -Kritikern, es taucht dementsprechend in den Feuilleton-Teilen der Medien auf. Wird verwendet, ist ernst gemeint.